# how to emulate public dir with mod_rewrite

Tags: mod-rewrite, public-html

I keep my website files in `/public/` directory.

So, for example, to access css file, if we point absolute html path, it would be

`/public/css/reset.css`.

I have `/public/index.php` file that handles every request. So, my main site API works fine.

Here's my simple .htaccess: (outside the `public` dir)

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|png|css|html)$ public/index.php
</IfModule>
```

How can I add mod_rewrite rules, so, when I ask `mysite.com/css/reset.css` I get `mysite.com/public/css/reset.css` (so, for other files too)

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteCond -f public%{REQUEST_URI}
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I've tried this. It doesn't work ;( When I open `mysite.com` it opens directory of my site

Comment: it works only if I point `http://mysite.com/public/$1` instead of `public/$1`, and works without RewriteCond. And it's possible to not redirect directly? I mean not to show /public/ path in url?